# A-Frame web component compatibility

Tags: web-component

I have had a look at the A-Frame 3d/Virtual Reality specification:

[aframe.io](https://aframe.io)

Although it appears to nod in the direction of Web Components it doesn't appear to conform to the emerging Web Components standards.
As someone has already pointed out on Stackoverflow it uses document.registerElement which is deprecated.

Is it intended that A-Frame will comply with the Web Components standards?

Answer (score 0):

According to old issues [here](https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/issues/2562) and [here](https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/issues/3182) on A-Frame github repository:

> It's something we'll look at once there's wide support of V1. But switching from polyfill to polyfill will likely introduce bugs due to how closely A-Frame relies and overrides the current one. A-Frame doesn't use vanilla registerElement behavior.

`registerElement()` is deprected but they use a polyfill, so it will still work in the future.

You'd better ask directly to A-Frame for an update.